# ListBoxItem background color

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want upon selection to change the background color of the item, however i can't seem to find a way to do it.
I'm trying to use the code below but can't find the completion for it, and i need to set the colror to a custom one such as "#8e8e8e":

```
private void list_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (list.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            ListBoxItem a = sender as ListBoxItem;
            //a.Background=

            PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["test"] = list.SelectedItem;
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Detail", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        list.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

So i need to chnage the selected item background color to **#8E8E8E** from C# for simplicity because changing the states seems a bit complicated especially that all i need to do is change background color of the selected item.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Although not recommend like Matt already pointed out you should be able to achieve this by using ControlTemplates and Visual States. Check out this article on windowsphonegeek to see how: [Part 1](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/How-to-customize-the-WP7-ListBox-Selected-Item--Part1-Control-Template) [Part 2](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/How-to-customize-the-WP7-ListBox-Selected-Item--Part2-Visual-States)

Please let us know if you encounter any problems

Comment: I did check this link before and to be honest it didn't help much :(
I used the template in the post however something seemed to be missing and i'm new to the template binding thing so this is why i'm trying to solve this with C# code rather than templates.

Comment: I know how you are feeling, I also experienced problems when trying to use it for the first time. Right now I don't have the time to figure this out for you, but I'll try to get back to you this weekend if no other solution showed up yet

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the visual states for selected items if you wish to do this.

However, standard behaviour for Metro apps and recommended design best practices advise not to use colour to indicate selection in anythign other than the ListPicker.
Without seeing your app, how you're using the ListBox or the purpose of indicating selection it's hard to advise further though.